# What's the best way to write cross-platform shell scripts

Tags: bash, shell, cross-platform

I have a shell script I'd like to run on multiple platforms that all support bash. My issue is that some commands behave differently on Linux, FreeBSD, OS X, and Cygwin.

My thought so far are:

- Create default implementations of functions for all the OS-specific operations in the main script, then inspect `$OSTYPE` and `source` an implementation-specific file that (optionally) replaces commands that behave differently. And if I do this, how should I handle commands with several arguments? Four positional arguments passed to a function isn't the cleanest approach.
- Put all the implementations in my script, each with an affix in the name, inspect `$OSTYPE` and create an `OPSUFFIX` variable, then call `operation$OPSUFFIX` for each operation.
- `./configure` magic?
- Migrate to something like Python—maybe the most sensible, but requires the most code changes. And if this is an idiomatic init script, this isn't an option.

Comment: If you want something truly cross platform then you need to migrate away from scripting into programming - there are many languages that abstract the OS implementation from the code; Python, Ruby, Java just to name a few. If you are making Windows users install Cygwin (eew) then making them install one of the others is not big ask.

Comment: Many standard commands have standardized behaviour for much of what they do. If you can manage to stay within that zone (and can assert `bash`, which isn't necessarily something you can reasonably assert) you can generally write a mostly portable script.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Nothing wrong with using Cygwin or UWin as part of ones own workflow especially for using your scripts cross-platform. I have no idea how people get by without Cygwin.

Comment: POSIX (Portable Operating System Interface) was defined for this very reason. If you stick to commands defined by the POSIX specification, and only use options defined by POSIX, your script will be about as portable as can be expected. Further, you might consider writing the script in POSIX `sh` rather than `bash`, so that the script will work regardless of which (POSIX-compatible) shell is present.

Comment: It is heavily dependant of what you want to do in your script (ex: file place,name,behavior). I often do this (AIX/SUN/Linux) and unluckily i create a list of specific behaviour and overload the script based on OS/Version. See the different use of sed depending of version and OS or simply a pipe behaviour that sometime need a new line (SUN) where other OS in "same" shell not.

Comment: @chepner You're right about bash, I don't think there's a POSIX `adduser`.

Answer (score 1):

First, where possible find ways of doing what you want where the differences will not matter.  As an example some versions of tar used to not support the -z option for handling gzipped files.  However combining tar and gzip was portable.  Similarly there are ways of invoking ps that generally work both on BSD and LINUX.

Once you find you still have things you need to deal with, your approach of sourcing a file to provide functions that handle the command syntax seems reasonable.  To avoid positional arguments you can use getopt which is a bash built-in.

An alternative may be to write a python script or similar that just encapsulates the worst of the platfrom-dependent command behavior.